# Apache NiFi & Fault Tolerance

Tags: apache-nifi

Is Apache NiFi Fault Tolerant ?

Let's say my NiFi cluster has 3 nodes, if one node goes down in the middle of processing, how does NiFi ensure my data is processed ?

As I understand from Hortonwork forums, NiFi does not replicate flow files, but the answers are a bit old now. Is there any updates to this ?

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/46887/is-nifi-fault-tolerant-against-machine-failures.html

Answer (score 2):

The link you included in your post (and the links in that post) are indeed outdated, although some of the information in that post is still relevant. The NiFi Documentation is up to date and explain nicely how clusters work.

To answer your question in short, if a node fails, the data that was on that node when it failed will require manual intervention to recover. If you lose the storage on the failed node, you lose the data on that node. The rest of the cluster will keep on working, depending on how you configured your cluster.